# Laravel - Formatting string values in Collection retrieved via pluck()

Tags: php, string, laravel, collections

I have a table `abilities` and it has some entries in it (sorry for not making it into a table format, I don't know how to do that):

```
-id|name
-1|create_user
-2|delete_user
-3|ban_user
```

Righty o, when I run the following code:

```
$abilities = App\Ability::all()->pluck('name','id')
```

I get the following output in tinker:

```
 Illuminate\Support\Collection {#861
 all: [
   1 => "create_user",
   2 => "delete_user",
   3 => "ban_user",
 ],
```

}

I want it to appear something like: `1=>"Create User"`...i.e. underscore replaced with space and both words capitalised. How do I go about that? I am trying this out for the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor):

```
public function getModifiedNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst(str_replace('_', ' ', $value));
}
```

And use it:

```
$abilities = App\Ability::pluck('modified_name', 'id');
```

Comment: That's good but for getting something like 'Created User', it will be better to use `return ucwords( );`

Answer (score 0):

You can deal this in your model itself like below

```
     /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNameAttribute()
    {
        return ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $this->name)); 
    }
```